# What version of clang is in llvm 4.2 which is in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode, llvm, clang

I am unable to find the version number for the clang in llvm in Xcode. Aside from knowing the answer, I'd like to know how to find it. I've looked everywhere I can think of online as well as in Xcode. I can find older answers that show obsolete information in this regard but nothing that has either a current answer or a current method for getting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you should input "clang --version" into a terminal.  There you will get three sets of version numbers.  The first is the version of Apple's LLVM which is tied to the XCode version.  Second is the internal build version of clang itself and finally is the version of LLVM that the build was based upon.

e.g. Doing this to my own machine I get the following

Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)

Comment: Is there any way to know what the relationship between apple's version of clang is to the "official" clang repo?